# Can't access user Exchange mailbox on certain machines

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to run the following code as my own user.

```
var email = UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.AutodiscoverUrl(email);
FolderId inbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox(email));
service.FindItems(inbox, new ItemView(1000));
```

This code works on one machine, but not on a new machine. Instead I get this exception

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties.
  Source=Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary() in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Responses\ServiceResponse.cs:line 277
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute() in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\Requests\MultiResponseServiceRequest.cs:line 166
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems[TItem](IEnumerable`1 parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, String queryString, ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandlingMode) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ExchangeService.cs:line 832
       at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(FolderId parentFolderId, ViewBase view) in \\REDMOND\EXCHANGE\BUILD\E15\15.00.0913.015\SOURCES\sources\dev\EwsManagedApi\src\EwsManagedApi\Core\ExchangeService.cs:line 956
```

I can't really see any differences between the machines other than

- The failing machine is a new install, so it might be missing some framework components or something?
- I don't have admin rights on the failing machine, but I'm not running as admin on either machine.
- The failing machine has Outlook 365 installed while the working machine has Outlook 2013 installed. I'm not sure why this would be an issue though, since they are both talking to the same Exchange server.

The really confusing thing is that I have two accounts configured in Outlook under Account Settings (the second one is a service account mailbox). If I change the `email` variable to the second account's email address, everything works fine. This is leading me to believe it's not strictly an issue with admin rights, but I can't quite figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Is it because the "first" on the list is an additional, not the main?

Comment: The first one is my personal account, tied to my domain login, etc. The second one is a service account that I added manually in Outlook.

Comment: Ok, that makes less sense, it would make more sense if it barfed on the service account

Comment: Right, exactly. I would expect to always be able to access my own mailbox without issue. That's what's so strange.

Comment: Any chance the Ad object doesnt have an actual email in it for your account? or maybe has an older company email address listed or something

Comment: If I change it to hard-code my email address it still fails (but works if I run with admin).

Comment: it sounds almost like theres tighter security on your account which doesnt allow it to prove its there even as your account the resolve URL portion acts like its under a guest type account

Comment: Strangely enough, this seems like it's dependent on the machine I run it on? Running it on different machines, both without elevated permissions have different results (only one throws an exception). Is it possible something needs to be installed specifically for this to work?

Comment: Confirmed that the XML being sent is the exact same in both cases, so it must have something to do with the authentication piece?